# Custom UserDetailsService Not Being Called - Grails & Spring Security Core

Tags: grails, spring-security, userdetailsservice

I'm using Grails v2.4.2 with spring-security-rest, spring-security-core, and spring-security-ui plugins.

I've written a custom UserDetailsService to make the username case-insensitive. All I am doing is simply trying to override

```
UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles) throws UsernameNotFoundException
```

My **com.example.core.CaseInsensitiveUserDetailsService** class is defined as:

```
class CaseInsensitiveUserDetailsService extends GormUserDetailsService {

    /**
     * Make The Username Case Insensitive
     */
    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username, boolean loadRoles) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Person.withTransaction { status ->

            log.debug "Case Insensitive User Details Service"

            // Find The Username
            def user = Person.findByUsernameIlike(username)

            // If User Not Found, Throw Exception
            if (!user) {
                log.warn "User not found: $username"
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found', username)
            }

            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = loadAuthorities(user, username, loadRoles)
            createUserDetails user, authorities
        }
    }
}
```

My **resources.groovy** contains:

```
beans = {

    userDetailsService(com.example.core.CaseInsensitiveUserDetailsService)

    credentialsExtractor(Grails24CredentialExtractor)

    // Some Custom Filters Are Also Defined (securityContextRepository, securityContextPersistenceFilter, multipartResolver)

}
```

It compiles succesfully, but it never actually runs my custom **CaseInsensitiveUserDetailsService**. In the console, I see debug statements from the actual GormUserDetailsService instead of my custom one. What can be done to use my custom UserDetailsService?

** **Note:** I've been following these two tutorials:

1. http://www.stevideter.com/2012/11/17/case-insensitive-usernames-using-spring-security-core-plugin-for-grails/
2. http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/userDetailsService.html

Comment: Have you created this as a plugin that is then installed into an application?

Comment: Nope, it's just simply a class

Comment: Can you show your configuration (interested in the the security and logging sections) and the output of the request and the response?

Comment: @JeremyWagner how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when doing something similar with a different plugin and Spring Security, and the wiring needed to be made explicitly to be by name.  Try in `resources.groovy`:

```
userDetailsService(com.example.core.CaseInsensitiveUserDetailsService) { bean->
    bean.autowire = "byName"
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Autowiring is more convenient since you don't need to explicitly define each one, but you can always do that if you want

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this example for educational(self) purposes, perhaps it might help: 
https://github.com/grails-coder/grails-spring-security

It regards to:

- Authentication Providers
- Custom UserDetailsService

Kindly notice it's on top of grails 3.2.5