# Grails spring bean in not loaded (custom UserDetailsService)

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-bean

I use custom implementation for Spring Security Plugin to override a default loadUser function.  I read this manual https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/userDetailsService.html and this is my resources.groovy file:

```
package spring

import security.ExtendedUserDetails
beans = {
  UserDetailsService(ExtendedUserDetails)
}
```

but it was didn't loaded. App still use a default puligin implementation GormUserDetailsService. I use debugger and I see that ExtendedUserDetails never run.

So what's wrong?

This question is unanswered yet
[Custom UserDetailsService Not Being Called - Grails & Spring Security Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630568/custom-userdetailsservice-not-being-called-grails-spring-security-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a typo in your bean name in `resources.groovy`. The name must be `userDetailsService` not `UserDetailsService` (capital **U**) and `ExtendedUserDetails` must implement `GrailsUserDetailsService`.

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo.